# Class 'Artisaninweb\SoapWrapper\ServiceProvider' not found in vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I want to add soap service to my laravel 5.3 project.I have added service provider
in config/app.php

```
'aliases' => [
    'SoapWrapper' => Artisaninweb\SoapWrapper\ServiceProvider::class,   
    'SoapClient' => SoapClient::class,
],
```

In bootstrap/app,php I have added

```
$app->register(Artisaninweb\SoapWrapper\ServiceProvider::class);
```

my composer.json is like

```
"require": {
        "php": ">=5.6.4",
        "laravel/framework": "5.3.*",
        "laravelcollective/html": "^5.3.0",
        "artisaninweb/laravel-soap": "0.2.5.10",
        "hashids/hashids": "^1.0",
        "maatwebsite/excel": "~2.1.0"
    },
```

In my controller

```
use Artisaninweb\SoapWrapper\Facades\SoapWrapper;
use SoapClient;
```

and cleared cache as  and composer

```
composer dumpautoload -o
composer clearcache
```

Still I'm getting a fatal error

> Fatal error: Class 'Artisaninweb\SoapWrapper\ServiceProvider' not
>   found in
>   C:\wamp64\www\pjct_name\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php
>   on line 610

What I have missed

Comment: You have added `aliases` in app.php, but have you added in `'serviceProviders` ?

Comment: added only in aliases in app.php

Comment: Add the service provider in `app/config/app.php`: 

`'Artisaninweb\SoapWrapper\ServiceProvider'` Please see this: https://github.com/artisaninweb/laravel-soap

Comment: can you give some sample

Comment: I have already gave you a link to visit! Plz see my above comment.

Comment: added 'providers' => [Artisaninweb\SoapWrapper\ServiceProvider::class,]but still have the same issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159736/discussion-between-user3386779-and-hiren-gohel).

Comment: composer dump-autoload, php artisan config:clear

Comment: Have you run `composer update` to install dependencies?